# UIButton - Giving the button an action?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have made a button through code (not on my storyboard) and yes it shows up no problem but now I want it to do an action when it is pressed.

> Code for button:

```
let backToHomeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
backToHomeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
backToHomeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
backToHomeButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backToHomeButton.addTarget(self, action: "Action: ", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(backToHomeButton)
```

and I want it to go back to the mainScreen.

> I have tried this and did not work:

```
let backToHomeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
backToHomeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
backToHomeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
backToHomeButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backToHomeButton.addTarget(self, action: "Action: ", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuViewController") as! UIViewController
self.view?.addSubview(backToHomeButton)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let backToHomeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
backToHomeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
backToHomeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
backToHomeButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backToHomeButton.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(backToHomeButton)
```

// present

```
func Action(sender:UIButton)
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuViewController") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

//second Option if you are pushing back to main view

```
func Action(sender:UIButton)
{
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

// or the previous controller

```
 func Action(sender:UIButton)
  {
 navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }
```

Comment: As a good practice the name of a instance method should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Dont blame me, look at the name of that function in that original question :)

Comment: I think this technically answers the OP's question, but if the OP wants to "back," it's best not to present another view controller instead...

Comment: @Lamar If there is an error on the question, you should not continue to made the same error and you should correct it.

Comment: @Lamar when I type `presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` I get an error saying use of "unresolved identifier 'presentViewController' "

Comment: put **self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)**

Comment: there is just a slight issue I have my everything under GameScene and GameScene does not have a member called presentViewController. Is there any way I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an Action to the button, and Dismiss the view in the action method:

For the button copy this:

```
let backToHomeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
backToHomeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
backToHomeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
backToHomeButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backToHomeButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then just add this method. And choose the dismiss method depending on how you presented the view. If not sure try one then the other.

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

   //IF YOU PRESENTED THE VIEW AS A MODAL

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});

   //IF YOU PUSHED INTO THE VIEW

    navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true) 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If the view controller is already in the navigation stack but it is not immediately before the current one the method `popToViewController(_:animated:)` should be used instead.